# ppscsi patch for 3.x kernel (14.04) progress/availability?? (kernel-patch-ppscsi-2.4)

Tags: 14.04, sane

Under 2.6.x kernel(s) there were a set of patches allowing attachment of so-called parallel port scsi devices like my fine hp 5100c flatbed scanner.
Recently upgraded to Trusty 14.04 with 3.13.x kernel and no similar support/patches have I yet found.

Closest reference google locates is bug report on package "kernel-patch-ppscsi-2.4":
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source...ugs?advanced=1

Any way I can find more on the status/progress of said package/patch/bugfix (or alternative)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That patch is for old 2.x kernels and is no longer maintained, either in Debain or upstream.

http://cyberelk.net/tim/parport/ppscsi.html

> NB: Grant (grant aT torque dot net) has not been able to work on ppSCSI since the middle of '99 owing to other priorities. For a short while after that, I (twaugh aT redhat dot com) had been keeping the ppSCSI suite current with 2.2 and 2.3 kernels. However they are now no longer maintained. For the patches, see:
>
> http://people.redhat.com/twaugh/parport
>
> I would recommend addressing any correspondence concerning these drivers to the linux-parport mailing list, rather than directly to me.

Your only option is to examine the patch and see if you can adapt it for 3.x kernels.